# JavaScript query string

Tags: javascript, query-string

Is there any JavaScript library that makes a dictionary out of the query string, `ASP.NET` style?

Something which can be used like:

```
var query = window.location.querystring["query"]?
```

Is *"query string"* called something else outside the `.NET` realm? Why isn't `location.search` broken into a *key/value collection* ?

**EDIT**: I have written my own function, but does any major JavaScript library do this?

Comment: found this: http://medialize.github.com/URI.js/

Comment: See also [How can I get query string values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values)

Comment: Very duplicated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Comment: @davidtaubmann that one is older, it would be inverse. Funny that they essentially ask the same, but due to the format of the question one got the glory turned into community's, and other closed as off-topic.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Maybe http://plugins.jquery.com/query-object/?

This is the fork of it https://github.com/sousk/jquery.parsequery#readme.

Comment: This should be native to jquery

Comment: @EvanMulawski Thanks. The plug-in just disappeared it seems. I added a different link, which might help.

Comment: The method provided by CMS is easier and cleaner.  Esp. if you are not already using jquery.

Comment: @jcoffland I agree. I use a regex something like that myself for parsing mailto URIs.

Comment: You can refer this library to do that - https://github.com/Mikhus/jsurl

Comment: Here's the proper link: http://plugins.jquery.com/query-object/

Answer (score 231):

You can extract the key/value pairs from the [location.search](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location) property, this property has the part of the URL that follows the ? symbol, including the ? symbol.

```
function getQueryString() {
  var result = {}, queryString = location.search.slice(1),
      re = /([^&=]+)=([^&]*)/g, m;

  while (m = re.exec(queryString)) {
    result[decodeURIComponent(m[1])] = decodeURIComponent(m[2]);
  }

  return result;
}

// ...
var myParam = getQueryString()["myParam"];
```

Comment: This is not a win. What if a key's value has the '=' character in it? E.g. dork.com/?equation=10=2. You could argue it SHOULD be URL-encoded but it sure doesn't have to be. I made the mistake of writing a naive function like this myself once. There are more than one edge case this function account for.

Comment: @James, forgot to mention that a couple of months ago I've modified the function, now it correctly can handle your example `dork.com/?equation=10=2` ...

Comment: @CMS this doesn't handle the possibility of an array in a query string that is represented as such `?val=foo&val=bar&val=baz`  how would you accomodate this?

Comment: i just realized this is a very old post, but here is a possible solution: http://pastie.org/1418228

Comment: @RussBradberry You can't really have `val=foo&val=bar&val=baz`; it would have to be `val[]=foo&val[]=bar&val[]=baz`

Comment: How do I get the same result in Ajax ?

Comment: I think your first one is better but awesomeness in either case.

Comment: It seemed incomplete to me when my values had spaces and my vars ended up with `%20`'s, so I replaced `result[keyValuePair[0]] = keyValuePair[1] || '';` with `result[keyValuePair[0]] = decodeURIComponent((keyValuePair[1]+'').replace(/\+/g, '%20')) || '';`

Comment: @CMS you should convert the expression inside the while loop to a boolean: `while (!!(m = re.exec(queryString))) {` so it can pass jsHint.

Answer (score 22):

## *tl;dr* solution on a single(ish) line of code using vanilla javascript

```
var queryDict = {}
location.search.substr(1).split("&").forEach(function(item) {
    queryDict[item.split("=")[0]] = item.split("=")[1]
})
```

For querystring `?a=1&b=2&c=3&d&e`it returns:

```
> queryDict
a: "1"
b: "2"
c: "3"
d: undefined
e: undefined
```

### *multi-valued keys* and *encoded characters*?

See the original answer at [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21152762/985454)

```
"?a=1&b=2&c=3&d&e&a=5&a=t%20e%20x%20t&e=http%3A%2F%2Fw3schools.com%2Fmy%20test.asp%3Fname%3Dståle%26car%3Dsaab"
> queryDict
a: ["1", "5", "t e x t"]
b: ["2"]
c: ["3"]
d: [undefined]
e: [undefined, "http://w3schools.com/my test.asp?name=ståle&car=saab"]
```

Comment: that isn't a single line - it's several lines formatted badly!

Comment: Damn, I don't know what to say... You got me. Here, have some multilined solution: `    var queryDict = {};
    location.search.substr(1).split("&").forEach(
        function(item) {
            queryDict[item.split("=")[0]] = item.split("=")[1];
        }
    );`

Comment: haha I love it!  Sorry I used to work with someone who used to say 'I've found a one liner that does x' and then just show you 3 lines with the line breaks taken out!

Comment: @JonnyLeeds No problem, I know exactly what you mean, but then, why would one write each of chained commands on new line? Then there is a function given as parameter (parameters are usually inlined) which has only a single assignment. It screams to be inlined! :D

Comment: So, I've just received first downvote after a 14 upvote streak. Dear downvoter, mind shedding some light on it? :)

Comment: @Qwerty, it's probably because your "one-liner" should be reformatted so that reading it doesn't require horizontal scrolling. I have adjusted it.

Comment: This doesn't produce the results you've documented. `queryDict.a == 't%20e%20x%20t'`

Comment: @roydukkey If you have _encoded characters_ in your query, you should navigate to [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21152762/985454) There is a more complex solution.

Comment: @Qwerty My concern is that it doesn't create a array of value as suggested. ie. `["1", "5", "t e x t"]`

Comment: @roydukkey Yes, because for that you would have to follow the link provided, as the solution, which handles _multi-valued keys_ and _encoded characters_ is there and is more complex than the one above, which was tailored and simplified to fit the question.

Comment: Aw ic. That's not very clear I guess.

Comment: Thanks - this works wonderfully in Google Tag Manager.

Answer (score 8):

After finding this post, when looking myself I thought I should add that I don't think the most up-voted solution is the best. It doesn't handle array values (such as ?a=foo&a=bar - in this case I would expect getting a to return ['foo', 'bar']). It also as far as I can tell doesn't take into account encoded values - such as hex character encoding where %20 represents a space (example: ?a=Hello%20World) or the plus symbol being used to represent a space (example: ?a=Hello+World).

Node.js offers what looks like a very complete solutions to querystring parsing. It would be easy to take out and use in your own project as its fairly well isolated and under a permissive licence.

The code for it can be viewed here: https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/querystring.js

The tests that Node has can be seen here:
https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/test/simple/test-querystring.js I would suggest trying some of these with the popular answer to see how it handles them.

There is also a project that I was involved in to specifically add this functionality. It is a port of the Python standard lib query string parsing module. My fork can be found here: https://github.com/d0ugal/jquery.qeeree

Comment: There is no just borrowing the code from Node,js, it's highly intertwingled.

Answer (score 6):

Or you could use the library [sugar.js](http://sugarjs.com).

From sugarjs.com:

> **Object.fromQueryString ( str** , deep = true **)**
>
> Converts the query string of a URL into an object. If deep is false,
>   conversion will only accept shallow params (ie. no object or arrays
>   with [] syntax) as these are not universally supported.
>
> ```
> Object.fromQueryString('foo=bar&broken=wear') >{"foo":"bar","broken":"wear"}
> Object.fromQueryString('foo[]=1&foo[]=2') >{"foo":[1,2]}
> ```

Example:

```
var queryString = Object.fromQueryString(location.search);
var foo = queryString.foo;
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have the querystring on hand, use this:

```
 /**
 * @param qry the querystring
 * @param name name of parameter
 * @returns the parameter specified by name
 * @author eduardo.medeirospereira@gmail.com
 */

function getQueryStringParameter(qry,name){
    if(typeof qry !== undefined && qry !== ""){
        var keyValueArray = qry.split("&");
        for ( var i = 0; i < keyValueArray.length; i++) {
            if(keyValueArray[i].indexOf(name)>-1){
                return keyValueArray[i].split("=")[1];
            }
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
// How about this
function queryString(qs) {
    var queryStr = qs.substr(1).split("&"),obj={};
    for(var i=0; i < queryStr.length;i++)
        obj[queryStr[i].split("=")[0]] = queryStr[i].split("=")[1];
    return obj;
}

// Usage:
var result = queryString(location.search);
```

Comment: That's more-or-less the same as the "Update: no need to use regex" code in the [highest-voted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/647272/) above. There's also loads of similar code in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)). You're missing `decodeURIComponent` on the extracted strings at least.

Comment: @Rup, the update was made after this answer.

Comment: @Qwerty No it wasn't: the update was Feb 2013 whereas this answer was nearly a year later in Feb 2014. But who cares, there's plenty of similar code flying about. My comments about the `decodeURIComponent` stand, though.

Comment: @Rup Yup, sorry. And yup.

Answer (score 2):

#### The code

[**This Gist by Eldon McGuinness**](https://gist.github.com/EldonMcGuinness/6bccc6a0c62f85c378a6) is by far the most complete implementation of a JavaScript query string parser that I've seen so far.

Unfortunately, it's written as a jQuery plugin.

I rewrote it to vanilla JS and made a few improvements :

```
function parseQuery(str) {
  var qso = {};
  var qs = (str || document.location.search);
  // Check for an empty querystring
  if (qs == "") {
    return qso;
  }
  // Normalize the querystring
  qs = qs.replace(/(^\?)/, '').replace(/;/g, '&');
  while (qs.indexOf("&&") != -1) {
    qs = qs.replace(/&&/g, '&');
  }
  qs = qs.replace(/([\&]+$)/, '');
  // Break the querystring into parts
  qs = qs.split("&");
  // Build the querystring object
  for (var i = 0; i < qs.length; i++) {
    var qi = qs[i].split("=");
    qi = qi.map(function(n) {
      return decodeURIComponent(n)
    });
    if (typeof qi[1] === "undefined") {
      qi[1] = null;
    }
    if (typeof qso[qi[0]] !== "undefined") {

      // If a key already exists then make this an object
      if (typeof (qso[qi[0]]) == "string") {
        var temp = qso[qi[0]];
        if (qi[1] == "") {
          qi[1] = null;
        }
        qso[qi[0]] = [];
        qso[qi[0]].push(temp);
        qso[qi[0]].push(qi[1]);

      } else if (typeof (qso[qi[0]]) == "object") {
        if (qi[1] == "") {
          qi[1] = null;
        }
        qso[qi[0]].push(qi[1]);
      }
    } else {
      // If no key exists just set it as a string
      if (qi[1] == "") {
        qi[1] = null;
      }
      qso[qi[0]] = qi[1];
    }
  }
  return qso;
}
```

#### How to use it

```
var results = parseQuery("?foo=bar&foo=boo&roo=bar;bee=bop;=ghost;=ghost2;&;checkbox%5B%5D=b1;checkbox%5B%5D=b2;dd=;http=http%3A%2F%2Fw3schools.com%2Fmy%20test.asp%3Fname%3Dst%C3%A5le%26car%3Dsaab&http=http%3A%2F%2Fw3schools2.com%2Fmy%20test.asp%3Fname%3Dst%C3%A5le%26car%3Dsaab");
```

#### Output

```
{
  "foo": ["bar", "boo" ],
  "roo": "bar",
  "bee": "bop",
  "": ["ghost", "ghost2"],
  "checkbox[]": ["b1", "b2"],
  "dd": null,
  "http": [
    "http://w3schools.com/my test.asp?name=ståle&car=saab",
    "http://w3schools2.com/my test.asp?name=ståle&car=saab"
  ]
}
```

See also [**this Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cb57dusv/45/).

Answer (score 2):

It is worth noting, the library that John Slegers mentioned does have a jQuery dependency, however here is a version that is vanilla Javascript.

https://github.com/EldonMcGuinness/querystring.js

I would have simply commented on his post, but I lack the reputation to do so. :/

### **Example:**

The example below process the following, albeit irregular, query string:

```
?foo=bar&foo=boo&roo=bar;bee=bop;=ghost;=ghost2;&;checkbox%5B%5D=b1;checkbox%5B%5D=b2;dd=;http=http%3A%2F%2Fw3schools.com%2Fmy%20test.asp%3Fname%3Dst%C3%A5le%26car%3Dsaab&http=http%3A%2F%2Fw3schools2.com%2Fmy%20test.asp%3Fname%3Dst%C3%A5le%26car%3Dsaab
```

```js
var qs = "?foo=bar&foo=boo&roo=bar;bee=bop;=ghost;=ghost2;&;checkbox%5B%5D=b1;checkbox%5B%5D=b2;dd=;http=http%3A%2F%2Fw3schools.com%2Fmy%20test.asp%3Fname%3Dst%C3%A5le%26car%3Dsaab&http=http%3A%2F%2Fw3schools2.com%2Fmy%20test.asp%3Fname%3Dst%C3%A5le%26car%3Dsaab";
//var qs = "?=&=";
//var qs = ""

var results = querystring(qs);

(document.getElementById("results")).innerHTML =JSON.stringify(results, null, 2);
```

```html
<script 
src="https://rawgit.com/EldonMcGuinness/querystring.js/master/dist/querystring.min.js"></script>
<pre id="results">RESULTS: Waiting...</pre>
```

Comment: Actually, I did remove the jQuery dependency in the code I gave in my answer ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
function decode(s) {
    try {
        return decodeURIComponent(s).replace(/\r\n|\r|\n/g, "\r\n");
    } catch (e) {
        return "";
    }
}
function getQueryString(win) {
    var qs = win.location.search;
    var multimap = {};
    if (qs.length > 1) {
        qs = qs.substr(1);
        qs.replace(/([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/g, function(match, hfname, hfvalue) {
            var name = decode(hfname);
            var value = decode(hfvalue);
            if (name.length > 0) {
                if (!multimap.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
                    multimap[name] = [];
                }
                multimap[name].push(value);
            }
        });
    }
    return multimap;
}
var keys = getQueryString(window);
for (var i in keys) {
    if (keys.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        for (var z = 0; z < keys[i].length; ++z) {
            alert(i + ":" + keys[i][z]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also .toLowerCase() the name if you want hfname matching to be case-insensitive.

Comment: You can also check to see if the value is empty or not. If it is, you can skip adding the entry so the array only contains non-empty values.

Comment: unescape() doesn't handle UTF-8 sequences, so you might want to use decodeURIComponent(). However then, if you want + chars to be decoded to spaces, run .replace(/\+/g, " ") on the string before decoding.

Answer (score 1):

**I like to keep it simple, readable and small.**

```
function searchToObject(search) {
    var pairs = search.substring(1).split("&"),
        obj = {}, pair;

    for (var i in pairs) {
        if (pairs[i] === "") continue;
        pair = pairs[i].split("=");
        obj[decodeURIComponent(pair[0])] = decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
    }
    return obj;
}

searchToObject(location.search);
```

**Example:**

```
searchToObject('?query=myvalue')['query']; // spits out: 'myvalue'
```

Answer (score 1):

Function I wrote for a requirement similar to this with pure javascript string manipulation

```
"http://www.google.lk/?Name=John&Age=20&Gender=Male"

function queryize(sampleurl){
    var tokens = url.split('?')[1].split('&');
    var result = {};

    for(var i=0; i<tokens.length; i++){
        result[tokens[i].split('=')[0]] = tokens[i].split('=')[1];
    }

    return result;
}
```

Usage:

```
queryize(window.location.href)['Name'] //returns John
queryize(window.location.href)['Age'] //returns 20
queryize(window.location.href)['Gender'] //returns Male
```

Comment: Neat, but apart from the way you remove the leading `?` that's basically the same as the two answers above you?

Comment: Just a small improvement.
The way the method is used makes it easy for the user. User only needs to know what query string value he needs.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using lodash + ES6, here is a one line solution:

`_.object(window.location.search.replace(/(^\?)/, '').split('&').map(keyVal => keyVal.split('=')));`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, since everyone is ignoring my actual question, heh, I'll post mine too! Here's what I have:

```
location.querystring = (function() {

    // The return is a collection of key/value pairs

    var queryStringDictionary = {};

    // Gets the query string, starts with '?'

    var querystring = unescape(location.search);

    // document.location.search is empty if no query string

    if (!querystring) {
        return {};
    }

    // Remove the '?' via substring(1)

    querystring = querystring.substring(1);

    // '&' seperates key/value pairs

    var pairs = querystring.split("&");

    // Load the key/values of the return collection

    for (var i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
        var keyValuePair = pairs[i].split("=");
        queryStringDictionary[keyValuePair[0]] = keyValuePair[1];
    }

    // Return the key/value pairs concatenated

    queryStringDictionary.toString = function() {

        if (queryStringDictionary.length == 0) {
            return "";
        }

        var toString = "?";

        for (var key in queryStringDictionary) {
            toString += key + "=" + queryStringDictionary[key];
        }

        return toString;
    };

    // Return the key/value dictionary

    return queryStringDictionary;
})();
```

And the tests:

```
alert(window.location.querystring.toString());

for (var key in location.querystring) {
    alert(key + "=" + location.querystring[key]);
}
```

Mind you thought, JavaScript isn't my native tongue.

Anyway, I'm looking for a JavaScript library (e.g. jQuery, Prototype) that already has one written. :)

Comment: I'm not convinced you really need a library to do what amounts to three lines of code above! Still, at least you would hope a library would remember the decodeURIComponent() both the key and value, something every code snippet posted so far has failed to do.

Comment: You don't need a library. I wanted to compare my implementation to one in a library so I could see if I was missing any edge cases. :)

Comment: javascript isnt your native tongue what does it mean , you should learn it even if you need a library to use

Answer (score 0):

Building on the answer by @CMS I have the following (in CoffeeScript which can easily be converted to JavaScript):

```
String::to_query = ->
  [result, re, d] = [{}, /([^&=]+)=([^&]*)/g, decodeURIComponent]
  while match = re.exec(if @.match /^\?/ then @.substring(1) else @)
    result[d(match[1])] = d match[2] 
  result
```

You can easily grab what you need with:

```
location.search.to_query()['my_param']
```

The win here is an object-oriented interface (instead of functional) and it can be done on any string (not just location.search).

If you are already using a JavaScript library this function make already exist. For example [here is Prototype's version](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/String/prototype/toQueryParams/)