# How can I use Jquery show() hide() table rows based on a query string variable?

Tags: jquery

I have a landing page with several actions.  The action are within table rows that are hidden by default and open when a user clicks the action title.  I want to control what is shown/hidden based on a query string variable.

For example one of the actions is "Request a call."  There are links on other pages of the site to request a call.  When a user clicks that link I want them to go to the landing page with the "Request a call" row shown.

Comment: Can you show us your HTML, js code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nicked lots of stuff from [this article](http://www.nabble.com/method-plugin-for-getting-query-string-vars--td6919130.html#a6919130) and [CMS's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5445/cms) [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647259/javascript-query-string/647272) to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647259/javascript-query-string/647272).

Using a query string variable called showRow and passing it the id of the row to show (not fantastically sophisticated but a good starting point).

Using jQuery for the showing the requested row:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>col 1</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="row1" style="display: none;">
      <td>this is row 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row2" style="display: none;">
      <td>this is row 2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var row = getQueryString()["showRow"];
        if (row !== undefined) $("table tr#" + row + "").show();
    });

    getQueryString = function() {
        var assoc = [];
        var keyValues = unescape(location.search.substring(1)).split('&');
        for (var i in keyValues) {
            var key = keyValues[i].split('=');
            assoc[key[0]] = key[1];
        }
        return assoc;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: If you're putting it all in the one page you might need something a bit more like: http://www.contentwithstyle.co.uk/content/fixing-the-back-button-and-enabling-bookmarking-for-ajax-apps

Answer (score 0):

Could you not do some server side processing to generate the necessary processing? i.e using RAW PHP as you have not stated the server side language you could do:

```
<?
$showRow = "";
switch($_GET['title'])
{
   case "call":
   //$showRow is the id of the row to be shown
   $showRow ="call"
   break;
}
?>

...rest of page....

<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
    //show the row
    $("#<?=$showRow;?>").show();
   });
</script>
```

You could also set the id of the row to be the URL argument to cut out the need for a switch. You'd also need to do some null tests to make sure that the jquery doesn't try to show a row if a URL argument is not shown.

Comment: I'm always a bit nervous about embedding server side tags in JavaScript. Maybe consider putting it in a hidden variable on the page, and accessing through jQuery that way?

Comment: I can understand where you are coming from, that's why I stuck the switch in there to protect against any XSS attempt, the only value that could be passed to the JavaScript is one that is set in the server side code but is selected via the URL parameter.

The hidden input variable is always an option but I personally hate throwing them in unless absolutely necessary.