# Pass a variable to new page

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, userscripts

I am trying to pass a variable from one page, load another and enter that information.
something Like this:

When 127.0.0.1/test.html&ID=1234

```
location.href = "127.0.0.1/newpage.html"

if (location.href == newpage.html){
    var e = document.GetElementById("Loginbx");
    e.Value = ID
}
```

I don't have access to modify 127.0.0.1/test.html nor newpage.html but would like to pass variables to them from another. Is this possible?

Comment: When you change the location using `location.href`, script execution will stop and the new page will be loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass the values on the query string and then read those:

```
location.href = "http://127.0.0.1/newpage.html?foo=1&bar=2";
```

Then use location.search to get the query string and parse it with Javascript. Just make sure none of the query string terms collide with any others that may exist.

Comment: Also see [JavaScript query string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/647259/javascript-query-string).

Comment: so simple. i was getting 404's because i left out the "?" thanks for your advise.