# How to use saved variables saved in Javascript file after moving to new HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a javascript function where in one part, I perform an `AJAX` call and store some information.

In the same function, I move to a new `HTML` file.

```
window.location.href = "deals.html";
```

Once moving to the new `deals.html` file, how can I access the information I stored earlier?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass a variable to new page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3016449/pass-a-variable-to-new-page)

Comment: Why are you performing an AJAX request if you are going to navigate the user away anyway?

Comment: Thanks mavrosxristoforos... The method in that thread worked out.

Answer (score 0):

The information you stored using AJAX function resides in server now, you have to initiate another AJAX function to retrieve that information from the server when you get the new page.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a javascript function to keep the data using cookies and access it in next page. This will be executed just befor redirecting to another page.

Answer (score 0):

There is something called localStorage which is supported by latest browsers, you can use that to store response from first call, and use it second page.

Answer (score 0):

This can only be achieved if you use **`cookies`** in JavaScript because, as you are navigating to another html document you loose the **status** of all the variables in the already executed script.

So before navigating away to another page set **as many cookies as required**.

### **[References on cookies](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)**