# Passing value from C# codebehind to javascript

Tags: c#, javascript

What is the best way to pass a value from C# code to javascript?
Currently I am setting an asp.net hidden field in the Page_Load method.

Also if I pass a value using GET like

```
Response.Redirect("myurl.com/myPage.aspx?id=300");
```

how can I get the value of id from myPage using javascript?

Is there a nice way to do this in jquery?

Comment: To extract the values of the querystring from the URL, you may want to check out [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/647259/javascript-query-string/647272#647272) by [@CMS](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5445/cms) in another Stack Overflow post.

Comment: This is a good solution. I would give you a checkmark if I could.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function getParameter(name)
{
    name = name.replace(/[[]/,"\[").replace(/[]]/,"\]");
    var results = new RegExp("[\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)").exec(window.location.href);

    return (results != null ? results[1] : "");
}
```

Use the following code to get your parameter: `getParameter("id")`

Answer (score 0):

If there's one specific variable you want, you can use the `document.location` property and split out the part after `id=`

Answer (score 0):

Tim's idea is good.  You could also directly insert the values into the javascript with something like `var idValue = '<%= SomeProtectedProperty %>';` within your script.  That's for if you know it at load time.