# How do I read a GET variable from JavaScript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I get a particular GET variable in JavaScript or jQuery?

I want to pass it on in ajax script in this sort of way:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'foo/bar.php',
    data: { 
       search: $(this).val(),
       page: something //$_GET['page'] only in js
    },
    ...
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript query string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/647259/javascript-query-string)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/09/get-url-parameters-values-with-jquery.html

Answer (score 0):

what you try is almost correct, but you dont hav to label the data and you have a wron placed `}` in your code.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'foo/bar.php',
    { 
       search: $(this).val(),
       page: 'something'
    },
    ...
});
```

for more information, take a look at the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

**EDIT:** to read your get-variable, just do it like you always do: `$s = $_GET['search'];`. maybe you have to use `$.get` instead of `$.ajax` or set the request type for your `$.ajax`-call (don't know if it's POST by default, but you should be able to see this using firebug or something similar)

Comment: You can ignore that, that was basically just a type-o when I was providing an example of where I wanted to use it. The actual question is how to read the GET variable itself.