# Help with Jquery ( change query string value )

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing, query-string

My requirement is to parse query string, get value of a key.. modify it and add it back in query string.

I am retreving querystring in a variable.

```
var a_href =  jQuery('#linkHere').attr('href');
```

lets say my value is something like this : 
`a_href = "?position=1&archiveid=5000&columns=5&hash_ref="http://xxx.com"`

Now I want to retrieve `hash_ref` value. Please note that `hash_ref` is a `window.location` value, now i need to update it to add `window.location.hash` value to `hash_ref` and assign it back to `a_href` variable.

How can we do this with jQuery?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/647259/javascript-query-string

Answer (score 0):

use this - http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/parseuri

var theValue = parseUri(uri).queryKey.a_href

there is also a jQuery pluging (http://plugins.jquery.com/project/url_parser) based on this function.

I am also assuming that the url in your query string is actually url encoded so you may need to decode it, I can't remember off the top of my head