# Pull variable from Query String and add into JS redirect URL

Tags: javascript, query-string

I'm trying to get the value of a variable in the query string `example.com/?hop=test`

And then pass it to a JavaScript in this form:

```
var exitsplashpage = 'http://example2.com/?hop=original_hop';
```

How do I get the original hop variable value using JavaScript and what is the correct format to put it into the exitsplashpage var?

Thanks!

Comment: To extract the value, have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/647259/javascript-query-string

Comment: It should be simple string manipulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var exitsplashpage = window.location.search.match(/\?hop=([^\&]*)/)[1]
```

Comment: This is unsafe for more than one URL parameter.

Comment: I'd use ?|& to allow `?foo=bar&hop=poh&bar=foo`. Also OP is checking against `hop`. But that is kinda obvious.

Comment: Calm down, simple mistake on my part.  But if you want to go there, I would say it's also kinda obvious that the OP was not asking for `?foo=bar&hop=poh&bar=foo`.

Comment: Thank you. This worked with a minor modification:

`var exitsplashpage = 'http://example2.com/?hop=' + window.location.search.match(/[\?\&]hop=([^\&]*)/)[1];`

needed to include the redirect URL and I didn't mention, but the hop variable might not be the first in the query string.

Answer (score 1):

Using [this](http://pastie.org/1418228) `getQueryString()` function from [the link that @Felix Kling posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647259/javascript-query-string), you would do the following:

```
var exitsplashpage = 'http://example2.com/?hop=' + getQueryString()["hop"];
```

Either that, or have a look at [jQuery Query String Object](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/query-object), with which you'd do this:

```
var exitsplashpage = 'http://example2.com/?hop=' + $.query.get("hop");
```