# How do I access the header using AJAX?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Say for example I had had page with the url of:

foo.php?bar='blob'

Is it possible to get the value of blob?

For example:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","new_film_pro.php?x="+blob,true);
```

Thanks

Comment: Apologies for not being very technical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this function: http://www.netlobo.com/url_query_string_javascript.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jsp then

```
var blob="<%request.getParameter('bar')%>";
xmlhttp.open("GET","new_film_pro.php?x="+blob,true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should already know the value, if your xmlhttp call includes it, just parse the string

**EDIT**

```
function getArgs(url) {
    var args = new Object();
    var query = url.split("?")[1];
    var pairs = query.split("&");
    for (var i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
        var pos = pairs[i].indexOf('=');
        if (pos == -1) continue;
        var argname = pairs[i].substring(0, pos);
        var value = pairs[i].substring(pos + 1);
        args[argname] = unescape(value);
    }
    return args;
}
var args = getArgs("testing.php?foo=bar");
txtValue.value = args.foo;
```

Comment: Well blob is a variable, use it... you could make it globally available ie. outside the function.

Comment: It doesn't use it - my example is purely demonstrating what I want to do.

Comment: Ok, but you still know the url right?, then you'll need to parse that instead, Updated my post

Answer (score 0):

See [Pull variable from Query String and add into JS redirect URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657090/pull-variable-from-query-string-and-add-into-js-redirect-url/5657173#5657173)