# Strategies for switching between desktop and mobile version of the website

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

researching a couple of hours now, i want to find a clever solution for giving a user the opportunity to switch to the desktop version of the current mobile version of a website.

Technically that menas that i either have a dedicated mobile site or a single site with media queries making the design responsible.

For me the last option of a single website with responsive design is of great interest.

1.) What ways can you think of to manipulate design by the user?

2.) Should it be on the server side or client side? Pros/cons?

3.) What kind of experience do you have with possible solutions?

I'm aware that there are some questions already out there...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11146768/switching-between-mobile-and-desktop-site

[Switch From Mobile Version to Full Website (Desktop Version)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11314944/switch-from-mobile-version-to-full-website-desktop-version-solved)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/)

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this? there's a large amount of posts on stackoverflow asking how to use media queries and include an option to switch between mobile/desktop, but very few are helpful

Comment: i ended up with javascript putting an additional class to the body....and switch classes for mobile/desktop

Answer (score 0):

Easiest CSS fix would be:
Eg:

```
#wrap {
 width: 1020px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) { /* Screen which has a maximum width of 900px */

  #wrap {
    width: 500px;
  } 

}
```

Comment: and now how to swith back to desktop?

Comment: you need not, if the screen has more than `900px`, it'll show the default one. But, there's no switching involved, if you want to view the default one on a `900px` screen, that won't be possible with this code.

Comment: and thats the point...i want the user having the opportunity to switch...via link etc.