# Meta viewport has no effect on media query

Tags: html, css, media-queries, viewport

I am trying to write a functionality enabling users to switch between mobile and desktop layout. I am using media query for differentiation of the layouts:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    .... some definitions
}
```

My understanding is, VIEWPORT META tag should affect the media query. So, I think this

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=640" />
```

should cause positive evaluation of my condition

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px)
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't. Am I wrong? If yes, is there a way, how to affect the media query?

Comment: A variation of this question has been asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14706011/strategies-for-switching-between-desktop-and-mobile-version-of-the-website. It might be simplest to add and subtract a class to <body> via jQuery/javascript then have separate classes for each. It depends on how your current code is set up.

Comment: Another way is to remove the meta viewport tag if the user wants to force the desktop version of the site, and add it back to show mobile version https://css-tricks.com/user-opt-out-responsive-design/

Comment: Nathan - thanks for the hints and the links. I asked primarily asked about correlation between viewport META and media query as I was surprised, that my media query wasn't affected. Switching is another topic, which is quite nicely covered on Internet as you mentioned. Quentin explained that,

Comment: Your media query will be deactivated if the meta viewport tag isn't there, which actually answers your question, as that's the relationship between them. Initial size has to do with percentage rather than a static content width in pixels.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> My understanding is, VIEWPORT META tag should affect the media query.

Only in browsers that support it. Desktop browsers generally do not.

If you want to allow Desktop browsers to use CSS you normally only want for smaller screens, then your best bet is to use two separate `<link>` elements and use the `media` attribute to specify your media queries. Then use JavaScript to change the media queries to match the display (instead of the display to match the media queries).