# codeigniter mobile detection and desktop version

Tags: codeigniter, mobile

I can get mobile site in mobile phones using the code below in the default controller index function. But I want to browse desktop version again in mobile. Since the code above resides in default controller index function, there is no way to browse desktop site in mobile, please help

```
public function index() {
    $this -> load -> library('Mobile_Detect');
    $detect = new Mobile_Detect();
    if ($detect->isMobile()) {
        header("Location: ".$this->config->item('base_url')."/mobile"); exit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can check if the device is mobile and then ask the user if they would like the mobile version or the full version, and then load one or the other.

Also take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11314944/switch-from-mobile-version-to-full-website-desktop-version-solved) and see if it helps you.