# Using 'mailto' address from Windows to fill web form

Tags: html, windows, forms, batch-file

I am working on a project to allow a user to click an e-mail address in a program which will load a specific web-page and fill that address into the form on that page.  So far I've modified the registry so that clicking the address opens the site and logs the user in (with a simple batch file).  I just need help extracting the e-mail address to fill the form.
Thank you in advance for any help or suggestions, this is my first post!

Answer (score 1):

You may wish to approach it differently and instead use JavaScript from a plain link and pass the e-mail address in a querystring.

e.g. http://www.example.org?email=alex@example.com

And then you can get the value of e-mail from the querystring in javascript (perhaps using something mentioned here: [JavaScript query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647259/javascript-query-string))

Or accessing the querystring from a server side langiage such as ASP.net / php etc.
A simple example for [asp.net and querystrings](http://www.dotnetperls.com/querystring)

Then you can either draw out the e-mail in javascript:

```
document.getElementById("yourinputboxid").value = yourQuerystringValue;
```

or writing out using server-side code (asp.net etc)

I'd try to avoid doing anything that needs you to moifuthe registry. If you simply use a link with a querystring, then you can get the data using standard techniques.