# best way to split a string and get url values using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have string which is in url like below

```
?type=english&time=today
```

I want to get the values of type and time and curently doing like below

```
var str="?type=english&time=today";

var spt =str.split("&");
var typeval =spt[0].split("=")[1];
var timeval =spt[1].split("=")[1];

document.write(" type :"+typeval+" time : "+timeval);
```

What is the efficient way to get the values using javascript.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript query string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/647259/javascript-query-string)

Comment: @Daniel the question is certainly a dup, but the answers are somewhat outdated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [jQuery BBQ's](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/) [`$.deparam`](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-bbq/examples/deparam/) function.

```
var str='type=english&time=today',
    obj = $.deparam(str),
    typeval = obj.type, // 'english'
    timeval = obj.time; // 'today'
```

It works with all sorts of fancy URL-encoded data structures (see the linked examples).

Comment: +1 For API reference, but ... icky style! Heh, I know, you'll just chide in with how I need more semicolons ;-)

Comment: @Matt thanks for jQuery reference..it's neat and less code is required.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the gup function- get url parameters:

```
function gup( name )
{
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
  var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );
  if( results == null )
    return "";
  else
    return results[1];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I always use this script:

```
function getUrlVars()
{
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');

    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }

    return vars;
}
```

then

```
var hash = getUrlVars();
alert(hash['type']);
```

will give 'english'

it's easily adaptable to what you want

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = {},
    str = "?type=english&time=today";

$.each(str.split(/&|\?/), function(){
    var tmp = this.split('=');
    ( tmp.length>1 ) && ( obj[ tmp[0] ] = tmp[1] );
})

// obj = { type : 'english', time : 'today' }
```