# Javascript Dropdown (Select)

Tags: javascript, html

So, I have this code:

```
<form id="a">

<select name="day1" id="day1">
<option value="01">01</option>
<option value="02">02</option>
<option value="03">03</option>
...
</select>

<select name="month1" id="month1">
<option value="01">Jan</option>
<option value="02">Feb</option>
<option value="03">Mar</option>
...
</select>

<select name="day2" id="day2">
<option value="01">01</option>
<option value="02">02</option>
<option value="03">03</option>
...
</select>

<select name="month2" id="month2">
<option value="01">Jan</option>
<option value="02">Feb</option>
<option value="03">Mar</option>
...
</select>

<input type="submit" value="Submit" />

</form>
```

I need the script to redirect the browser to

> http://example.com/?from=AA-BB&to=XX-YY

after the form is submitted.

AA would be the selected value from select area "day1",

BB would be the selected value from select area "month1",

XX would be the selected value from select area "day2",

YY would be the selected value from select area "month2"

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
var day1 = $('#day1 option:selected').text();
var month1 = $('#month1 option:selected').text();
var day2 = $('#day2 option:selected').text();
var month2 = $('#month2 option:selected').text();
var suffix = 'from=' + day1 + '-' + month1 + '&to=' + day2 + '-' + month2;
window.location = 'http://mypage.com/?' + suffix;
```

Comment: I used to think I knew some jQuery but, the more I read the good answers here at stackoverflow; the more I see how much more I have to learn. That's great!

Comment: @zzzzBov it was unclear if the OP wanted the value or the text.  If they wanted the value then yes `val()` would be more appropriate.

Comment: We always assume the "other" party has the remainder of the puzzle but, just in case, DonCroce, you will need to, of course, put a onSubmit='your-on-submit-processing-function();' and put all that stuff that JaredPar handed to you in there.

Answer (score 0):

In plain javascript, you can do the following (separated into the variables as you represented them):

```
function submitHandler() {
    var AA = document.a.day1.value;
    var BB = document.a.month1.value;
    var XX = document.a.day2.value;
    var YY = document.a.month2.value;

    location.href = "http://example.com/?from=" + AA + "-" + BB + "&to=" + XX + "-" + YY;
}
```

Then set `onsubmit` for your form, as follows:

```
<form name="a" onsubmit="submitHandler(); return false;">
```

Comment: still redirects me to index.php?day1=03&month1=11&day2=08&month2=11 The variables are okay, I've tested them in an alert. The whole url with the params gets alerted correctly - The form still gets submitted though and I end on my index.php, no redirect took place to example.com

Comment: added <form name="a" onsubmit="submitHandler();return false;"> and works now :)

Comment: Good catch; I've updated the answer accordingly, for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

How about...

```
var sFrom="02-03",sTo="03-02";

var from = sFrom.split('-');
var to= sTo.split('-');
console.log(from);
console.log(to);

$('select#day1 > option[value="'+from[0]+'"]').attr('selected','selected');

$('select#month1 > option[value="'+from[1]+'"]').attr('selected','selected');


$('select#day2 > option[value="'+to[0]+'"]').attr('selected','selected');

$('select#month2 > option[value="'+to[1]+'"]').attr('selected','selected');
```

As for the querystring retrieval, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647259/javascript-query-string/647272#647272) link out