# Loop through URL GET variables with javascript

Tags: javascript, url, get

I know you can obtain an URL variable by calling `getUrlVars()["id"]`, however is there a way to get all (an unknown number of) variables in the URL? For a few reasons I am only allowed to do this on client side.

Comment: See the second answer (high-voted) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/647259/javascript-query-string

Comment: Cheers Michael, location.search.substring(1) works great.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this:

```
function getUrlVars()
{
        var vars = [], hash;
        var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
        for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
        {
                hash = hashes[i].split('=');                        
                vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
        }
        return vars;
}

var url_vars = getUrlVars();
for(var i in url_vars)
{
        alert(i + " == " + url_vars[i]);
}
```

Comment: Wow why didn't I just do getUrlVars()...now I feel like an idiot :(

Answer (score 1):

[mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)

```js
let url = new URL(a.href);
for (const [key, value] of url.searchParams) {

}
```