# Set the value for a hidden parameter from the URL using javascript

Tags: javascript, request.querystring

I'm trying to set the hidden field for 'item_number' from the Url QueryString for a paypal form.

So the URL will look like this "http://website.com/customize.aspx?item_number=FFFF"

and code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('item_number').Value = Request.QueryString('item_number');
</script>

<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="">
```

But this doesnt work for me. Whats wrong here???? is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getElementById` only finds elements by their ID.  Your hidden doesn't have the `id` of `item_number`; it has that name, however.  If you add `id="item_number"` to your `input`, then the code should work.  You also need to move your script to *after* the DOM element.  Otherwise, it will run before the `input` exists in the document.

**Update**

Just noticed another mistake.  You're setting a `Value` property, and `Request.QueryString('item_number')` is also invalid.  It looks like you're confusing ASP.NET code with JavaScript.  The correct property name for the hidden input is `value` (lowercase).  There is no equivalent of `Request.QueryString` in JavaScript.  Rather, to extract query string values, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/647272/119549) for a good way to do so.

Comment: woops!! thanks for spotting those mistakes! But i've done what you said and its still not working... there must be another problem

Comment: thanks, i got it now. i shouldn't have assumed that Request.QueryString would work