# GET Variable + Javascript No Trim IE

Tags: javascript, get

I used the below code to pull a get variable from URL. It works in Chrome and FF but not in IE.

```
www.example.com/index.php?link=123
```

In Chrome/FF, the variable `first` returns `"123"` but in IE the variable `first` returns `"www.example.com/123"`

Any ideas on how to fix the code so that in IE it returns `"123"`?

```
function getUrlVars() {
  var map = {};
  var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value {
    map[key] = value;
  });
  return map;
}

var first = getUrlVars()["link"];
```

Comment: This post might be something like what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/647259/javascript-query-string

Comment: What version of IE?  Your code seems to work fine in IE9.

Comment: just 5.5. I guess its not as big of a problem as originally expected. Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: @Erica thanks for the post. It really helped out.