# How can I read a query string from js

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get query string values in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

I need a function to read query string value?

If I give key then the method should return the corresponding value.

Please help..

Comment: Add some example code of what you have [tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)!

Comment: This might be a solution.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/647272/999312

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this will help

```
function fnGetValueByKey(key)
{
  key = key.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]" + key + "=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
  var results = regex.exec(window.location.search);
  if(results == null)
    return "";
  else
    return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ive allways used the following and it seems to work

```
function urlParam(name){
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
    var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
    var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
    var results = regex.exec (window.location.href);
    if (results == null)
        return "";
        else
        return results[1];  
}
```

You just need to call `urlParam("yourName");` and it will return your value;

Comment: Looks disturbingly close to this http://stackoverflow.com/a/901144/995876

Comment: Yer its commonly used every where, ive been using it for years but im sure I got it from a forum or something at some point, im for sure not clever enough to write it myself ;)

Answer (score 0):

yAccess desired query using getQuery('mykey');

```
function getQuery( key) {
        var hu = window.location.search.substring(1), gy = hu.split("&"), val;
        keyValue = {};
        for ( var i = 0; i < gy.length; i++) {
            val = gy[i].split("=");
            keyValue[val[0]] = val[1];
        }
        return keyValue[key];
    }
```