# javascript to work when print=yes in the url

Tags: printing-web-page

Can anyone help me? I am looking for a javascript.
I would like to add "?print=yes" in my url like http://mywebsite.com/page1.html?print=yes

Once it is click and completely loaded the window.print() must then work.

Answer (score 0):

**How to check the value of a querystring**

[JavaScript query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647259/javascript-query-string)

**How to print from javascript.**

https://www.google.com.au/search?q=javascript+print