# HTML form - changing the select state from a link

Tags: javascript, html

I have been surfing round for an answer to this for most of my morning and I must be not using the right search terms because I cant find anything close to what im after.

It could be something possibly easy or might need some JS, i'm not sure as I have never had to do this in a project.

Basically I have some staff profiles, each profile has a link to the contact page.

```
<a href="contact_form">Contact Steve</a>
```

On "contact_form" there will be a select setup with the staff names, what I want to know is there a way I can pass information through the url to change the select state to show the correct name in the select state automatically.

```
<select name="Recipient">
        <option selected="selected" value="reception">Reception</option>
        <option value="steve">Steve</option>
        <option value="bob">Bob</option>
        <option value="john">John</option>
</select>
```

So in this case when the user clicks on "Contact Steve" when they get to the form that "Steve" is selected rather than "Reception" which is selected by default.

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify if the link goes to another page, or a contact form on the same page?

Comment: Yes sorry the profiles are on a different page, im trying to figure out how to pass something through the url to change the select state on a form on a different page, im just looking at some of the responses

Comment: You shouldn't have to use Javascript at all, and doing so is a needless dependency. You don't say how the staff profile page gets built, but I assume it's essentially a template where the staff info like the name "Steve" gets substituted. You can also set a query param in the link at the same time, for example `<a href="contact_form?contact=${contact_name}">Contact ${first_name}</a>` (or whatever the syntax is for *your* server-side technology)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `getQueryString` function from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/647272/86298). You could do the following:

```
function getQueryString() {
  var result = {}, queryString = location.search.substring(1),
      re = /([^&=]+)=([^&]*)/g, m;

  while (m = re.exec(queryString)) {
    result[decodeURIComponent(m[1])] = decodeURIComponent(m[2]);
  }

  return result;
}

window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    document.getElementById('contact-list').value = getQueryString()['contact'];
});
```

Note that you must set the ID of the select element like:

```
<select name="Recipient" id="contact-list">
```

Now, you can specify what contact to be selected using the URL:

```
contact_form.html?contact=steve
```

Answer (score 0):

using jquery:

```
<a data-id="steve" href="#contact_form">Contact Steve</a>

...

$("a").click(function() {
   $("select[name=Recipient]").val($(this).data("id"))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

When you redirect to contact form, provide some GET parameter like:
?rep=steve

// EDIT: OR if a click is done in contact form already, then use solution provided before mine // EDIT

On a contact form, use javascript:

```
var $_GET = [];
var get_arr = document.location.search.replace('?','').split('&');

for(var prm in get_arr){
dbl = get_arr[prm].split('=');
$_GET[dbl[0]] = dbl[1];
};
```

And then using a jQuery for example do:

```
$(function() {
if ( typeof($_GET['rep']) != 'undefined' ) {
$('select[name="Recipient"] option:eq("'+$_GET['rep']+'")').attr("selected","selected");
};
});
```

Might contain some syntax errors, unchecked.