# Get query string with JQuery, in a single line?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've searched all over the place, but I can't find a one post that gets a query string value in a single line, without writing a function themselves...

Isn't getting a value from a query string built into JQuery?

Comment: Hu... What ?... Can you explain with some little code what you want ?

Comment: No, getting query strings from the browser is not something that's built into jquery, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values

Comment: I think this might help you or at least get you started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/647259/javascript-query-string

Comment: Why does it have to be a single line? That's an odd requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Us regular expression to search key and then it corresponding value. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3RgXH/1/)

```
var value = location.search.match(new RegExp(key + "=(.*?)($|\&)", "i"))[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

start with `window.location.href`, then use string commands to substring at first '?'.