# JQuery get number after string in url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Really simple question for you guys (not so simple for me)

I have put together a script based on other threads here on StackOverflow but I have unique need.  There is a form on my site where users will submit it then it will add something like "?updated=555" to the url.  However this number changes depending on what they updated.

I need a way to search for just the number (555 in my example) so I can scroll back to that div when the form is submitted and page reloads.  Each div has a unique ID with a number that will match that query string when the url is submitted.  So all I need is a way to find out what the number is after "?updated=" so I can pass it to this

```
scrollTop: $("#my-number").offset().top
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    if(window.location.href.indexOf("?updated=") > -1) {
       $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#my-number").offset().top
        }, 2000);
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex to get the last number from your url:

```
var lastNumber = window.location.href.match(/\d+$/);
```

then use:

```
scrollTop: lastNumber
```

Answer (score 1):

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14663371/183181

```
function URLParameters(_querystring){
    var queryString = _querystring || window.location.search || '';
    var keyValPairs = [];
    var params      = {};

    queryString = queryString.replace(/^[^?]*\?/,''); // only get search path

    if (queryString.length)
    {
       keyValPairs = queryString.split('&');
       for (pairNum in keyValPairs)
       {
          if (! (!isNaN(parseFloat(pairNum)) && isFinite(pairNum)) ) continue;
          var key = keyValPairs[pairNum].split('=')[0];
          if (!key.length) continue;
          if (typeof params[key] === 'undefined')
             params[key] = [];
          params[key].push(keyValPairs[pairNum].split('=')[1]);
       }
    }
    return params;
}


var params = URLParameters();
params.updated; //[555]
```

So if you know it's only one value then, `params.updated[0]` or `params.updated.shift()` should equal `555`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of that, how about using bookmarks?

```
http://stackoverflow.com/url#updated555

<a id="updated555"></a>
```

otherwise...

```
var queries = location.query.split('&');
for(var i=0; i<queries.length; i++)
   if(queries[i].substr(0,8)==='updated=')
       $('html, body').animate({
         scrollTop: $("#"+queries[i].substr(8)).offset().top
       }, 2000);
```

...and you could still use bookmarks, since that's what they are for...

```
var query = location.hash;
if(query.substr(0,7)==='updated')
   $('html, body').animate({
     scrollTop: $("#"+query[i].substr(7)).offset().top
   }, 2000);
```