# Insert a java string into phonegap javascript

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am trying to insert a java string into phonegap javascript.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    String myName = "Xxxxx";

    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/login.html");
}
```

I just want to insert ***myName*** string into *login.html* so that I can use the string from javascript. Any idea plz?

is there any simpler way except plugin, like localstorage or anything else?
If it is must to make a plugin, then what is the way to fetch this string from here into that plugin?

I am new in both phonegap and android. Plz help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to pass sting via querystring, like

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    String myName = "Xxxxx";

    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/login.html?name=" + myName );
}
```

take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647259/javascript-query-string) to use querystring on javascript

Comment: Hi hkutluay, thanks for the suggestion. It works for me. Actually....just what I want... Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

In your MainActivity :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  JavaScriptInterfaceClass myInterface = new JavaScriptInterfaceClass(this, appView);
  appView.addJavascriptInterface(myInterface, "Android");

  super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/login.html");
}
```

Create a new class in your project for instantiating myInterface(works only for phonegap):

```
public class JavascriptInterfaceClass {
    private WebView mAppView;
    private DroidGap mGap;

public JavascriptInterfaceClass(DroidGap gap, WebView view) {
    mAppView = view;
    mGap = gap;
}

public String getMyString() {
  String myName = 'xxxxx';
  return myName;
```

}

In your WebView:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function getString() {
      return Android.getString();
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur help. (1) But it is showing error: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.minfb/com.minfb.PhoneGapActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException. (2) Another thing...`return Android.getString` or `return Android.getMyString`? any direction?

Comment: I hope the first answer did the trick in much simpler way. I haven't tried it before and thats why I answered with this one. Have no idea why it raises nullPointerException. I might use some more log information. and yes it's Android.getMyString() !

Comment: Yes, first one is very simple to implement. I have learned about java constructors by your answer. Thanks a lot.