# How to post to php value of href in a

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I've been able to retrieve all `<a href="">` with class `various`.

I need to write some script that grabs `href` from these `a` (everyone has different) and post it to popup.php.

Tricky part is that href has `gallery_popup.php??id=XX`, and the only thing that I need to post is that ID.

I decided to go with variables, so first:

```
var href = $('.various').attr('href');
```

I grab the href. Then I woul like to rip all unnecessary things and leave only ID number and save it to Var = IDnumber

And then

```
$(".various").click(function () {
   $.post('gallery_popup.php', IDNumber;
});
```

Comment: How are your `ID`'s being assigned? You could add a `rel` to them and grab that.
`<a href="..link.." rel="<? echo $ID; ?>">`
Then grab the REL attribute in jQuery: 
`$(".various").click(function () {
   $.post('gallery_popup.php', $(this).attr('rel');
});`

Comment: [JavaScript query string](http://stackoverflow.com/a/647272/1244588) just use your `href` instead of location.search

Answer (score 1):

or you can do

```
var myString = $(this).attr('href');
var myArray = myString.split('=');

$.post('gallery_popup.php', myArray[myArray .length-1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this :

```
$(".various").click(function () {
   var url = $(this).attr('href')),
       matches = url.match(/gallery_popup\.php\?\?id=(\d+)/),
       id;

   // If an id has been found, matches will contain 2 elements :
   //   1 - the whole chain matched (here "gallery_popup.php??id=XX")
   //   2 - the group captured (here XX)
   if(matches.length > 1) id = matches[1];

   $.post('gallery_popup.php', id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save Id number in "rel" like,

```
  <a href="gallery_popup.php??id=XX" rel="xx" class="various" >gallery</a>
```

Then you can access id,

```
    var href = $('.various').attr('rel');
```

If you want use

```
    var href = $('.various').attr('href');
```

You can split your url with 'id='

```
   eg: var temp = href.split("id=");
        alert(temp[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do it in one line:

```
$.post('gallery_popup.php', $(this).attr("href").split("=")[1]);
```