# how do I make a script to receive an argument through a URL?

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to JavaScript and I am trying to implement it into a website like this.

A person wants to download a file. They click on a link, which takes them to another HTML file with the download link, a keyword, and an advertisement.
So they would be on

```
http://website.com/randompage
```

And they would click on a link to download a file which would take them to

```
http://website.com/download.html?keyword=text?file_url=http://website.com/file.txt
```

If `website.com/download.html` could accept 2 parameters into an embedded JavaScript (or a seperate file, whichever works better). Then the download.html would show a link to download the file at variable `file_url` and would display the keyword from variable keyword. Then an ad would be displayed according to the keyword (my ad service does that for me).

Is this possible to do? I would like a sample script, if possible. The ad code can be left out (I already have that part).

Comment: You're looking for the query string: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/647259/javascript-query-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  hi
  <script>
    function getParam(paramName){
  var prmstr = window.location.search.substr(1);
  var prmarr = prmstr.split ("&");
  var params = {};

  for ( var i = 0; i < prmarr.length; i++) {
     var tmparr = prmarr[i].split("=");
     params[tmparr[0]] = tmparr[1];
  }
  return params[paramName];
}

    document.write('File url: ' +getParam('file_url')+ 
    '<br/>File name: ' +getParam('file_name')+ 
    '<br/>Keyword: ' +getParam('keyword'));
  </script>
</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: And I use this with the function `<script type="text/javascript">
    function $_GET(q,s) { 
        s = s ? s : window.location.search; 
        var re = new RegExp('&'+q+'(?:=([^&]*))?(?=&|$)','i'); 
        return (s=s.replace(/^?/,'&').match(re)) ? (typeof s[1] == 'undefined' ? '' : decodeURIComponent(s[1])) : undefined; 
    } 
</script>`

Comment: yes indeed, that's the definition of the $_GET function which you call to retrieve the URL parameter

Comment: Okay, thank you. I will accept this answer if my code works. It may take a while for me to implement it correctly.

Comment: ok, in case of any related questions, shoot

Comment: In the body, I put `var params = window.location.search.split('?');
var file_url = $_GET('file_url','?'+params[1]);` and it displays as normal text. Do I have to use the `<script>` tag to run JS in the body also?

Comment: yes you do. That way the browser knows you want to execute some code there. You might also need the `document.write()` method to write the file_url var: `document.write(file_url);`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36260/discussion-between-timtech-and-jeroen-ingelbrecht)

Comment: i can't access denied by company policy.. what's the problem?

Comment: It does not display anything on the page even with document.write. Can I use javascript variables outside of the script tags?

Comment: no, you cannot use js vars outside the script tags. Do you know JS Bin of jsFiddle? Can you paste your html and code there?

Comment: can you c/p the HTML in the question?

Comment: I wrote an example in the answer with html and js in the html

Comment: Okay, I will try it out soon.

Comment: It seems to work. Could you add the perms `file_name` and `keyword` to the existing `file_url`?

Comment: ok, i've altered the code

Comment: Um, `file.html?file_url=URL?file_name=FILE?keyword=KEY` displays:

`hi File url: URL?file_name
File name: undefined
Keyword: undefined`

Please help!

Comment: Fixed! In the code, `prmstr.split ("&");` should be `prmstr.split ("?");`

Comment: I accepted it. Thanks so much for your help!