# Pass parameter from one html page to another another using query string

Tags: javascript, html

Scenario is like there are three pages p1,p2,p3 and in p1 there are 3 buttons while i click a button it should go to p2 and in p2 there will be 2 buttons and ther if i click a button it should go to p3.
And in p3 i need detail of p1 so that i can create a summary table in besed on contents of p1,p2.
So can any one give a solution for passing parameter from page1 through to p3.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use query strings & read the query strings using **location.search**

Refer [JavaScript query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647259/javascript-query-string).