# how to get parameter values from url in javascript chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am working on chrome extension and want to extract keyword form url, the function works fine when keyword's value has one word but it does not work when it has two words. help please how i can improve it.

```
function getUrlVars(ar){
var vars = {};
var parts = ar.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
    vars[key] = value;
});
keyVal = vars;
return vars;
}
var keyword = getUrlVars(Url)["q"];
```

Comment: `var var`?? usign a reserverd keyword as variable name, that can't be right, now can it?

Comment: Can you show how you are formatting your url? Also, you should definitely never be using a reserved word for a variable name.

Comment: sorry its typing mistake

Comment: Can you show what the url you are passing in (the one with the keyword) looks like?

Comment: What are `parts` and `keyVal` supposed to do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript query string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/647259/javascript-query-string)

Answer (score 0):

There's a hundred ways to do it. If you separate the keywords with a symbol like + then here is a simple way to do it:

```
var Url = "http://thisurl.com/?q=whatever+something";

function getUrlVars(ar){
    var keyw = [], q;
    keyw = ar.split('?q=')[1].split('+');

    return keyw;
}

var firstFunction = getUrlVars(Url);
```