# $_GET['user'] php variable inside javascript code

Tags: javascript, php, variables

Here is my javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var country,url;
country = geoip_country_code()
if(country=="US"){
    url="http://www.site.org/index.php?user=php variable";
}
setTimeout("location.href = url;",5000);
</script>
```

i need put `$_GET['user']` php variable for get username in the current url

tried with this but not work

```
if(country=="US"){
    url="http://www.site.org/index.php?user=<?php echo $_GET['user']; ?>";
}
```

Comment: You can't mix PHP (server side) with javascript (client side). You can output the value of $_GET['user'] to the page with PHP or you can get the querystring variable with javascript.

Comment: This should work if the code executed as PHP code. Could you give more context? Also, this is probably a major security issue.

Comment: your code seems to be correct can you give us the exact output it is giving

Comment: I have done this several times, so the problem is other

Comment: @popnoodles — So what? The PHP engine doesn't care if some of the text it is outputting happens to be `<script type="text/javascript">`. There is a `<?php` at the point PHP code is written in the question.

Comment: The JS isn't being outputted by PHP. If it was it would work and they wouldn't be asking the question.

Comment: @popnoodles — Anything outside of `<?php ?>` will be outputted by the PHP engine when passed through it.

Comment: @Quentin where does OP say they are including `<script src="somejs.php">`?

Comment: @popnoodles — Since the code includes a script element, it is presumably inside an HTML document. They don't say if that HTML document has a `.php` file extension or not. If it doesn't (and it doesn't use an alternative method for passing it through the PHP engine) then the solution is "Give the file a .php extension" and not "you can't mix JavaScript and PHP"

Comment: No they don't. The question is too ambiguous. However, if that was all in a PHP file, tell me why it's not working. It seems obvious to me that that's javascript in a javascript file or in HTML that isn't outputted by PHP.

Comment: @user2893064 — Define "doesn't work". What is the outputted JavaScript (which you can see with View > Source)? What (if any) messages are displayed in your browser's JS console? What value are you giving to `user` in the query string?

Comment: @user2893064 can you tell us where that code is? How is it included in the page?

Comment: @popnoodles — There are several possibilities. The question doesn't have enough information to make it worth speculating at present.

Comment: code works in my localhost. Code executes first on server side so the value echos first. No problem there. if the guy wanted to get value by javascript in a php function that would be a problem.

Comment: thaks guys, yes the file is with .php extension.

Comment: @user2893064 — Define "doesn't work". What is the outputted JavaScript (which you can see with View > Source)? What (if any) messages are displayed in your browser's JS console? What value are you giving to user in the query string?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this in plain javascript:

```
var query = (function() {
    var result = {}, keyValuePairs = location.search.slice(1).split('&');

    keyValuePairs.forEach(function(keyValuePair) {
        keyValuePair = keyValuePair.split('=');
        result[keyValuePair[0]] = keyValuePair[1] || '';
    });

    return result;
})();

if(country=="US"){
    url="http://www.site.org/index.php" + (query.user !== undefined) ? "?user=" + query.user : "";
}
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/647272/838733 for the iffy specifics.

Answer (score 0):

This is the version using pure PHP:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://www.geoplugin.net/xml.gp?ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']";
$country = geoplugin_countryCode;
if($country=="US"){ 
    $url="http://www.site.org/index.php?user=$_GET['user']"; 
}
sleep(5);
header("Location: $url");
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming `$_GET['user']` is set:

```
var user = "<?php echo $_GET['user']; ?>";
url="http://www.site.org/index.php?user="+user;
```

Comment: Why would using an interstitial variable help?

Comment: Doing this would make no difference.