# Querystring in html5 banner

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem with an html5 banner.
I would need to send with a click macro with a querystring into banners.
Tex:
http://click.doman.com/click=135&programid=256&banner=367

And then I thought sending the clicktag like this:

http://www.mindoman.se/banner1.html?click=http://click.doman.com/click=135&programid=256&banner=367

So my question is:
How do I get the value from querystringen "click =" in banner1.html file?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Both Links lead to incorrect places ?

Comment: This is only an example..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values)

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/647259/javascript-query-string
?

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to add some static param to the URL, you can use Dynamic Parameter. The following URL explains how:

https://support.google.com/ds/answer/1649566?hl=en

But these dynamic parameters are tracking metrics and can not change your banner based on them and are not available in you banner.

If you want the variable to be available in the banner and banner content is going to be different in different situations. (You want external data be injected to you banner with a variable named 'click'), you should look at 'Dynamic Ad'

In normal banners you can not send extra information from DFP/DFA account.

The solution is to use 'Dynamic Content' in DoubleClick Studio.

The Dynamic ad is some kind of Rich Media banner which allows some predefined variables be injected into the banner. Then you can use those variable to adjust your visuals or even add extra query string to the exit url.

You should explain more about the 'click' variable and how it is calculated. Because in Dynamic Content you can have some predefined variables like: User Location, Time but not all kind of information. If these variables did not fit your requirements, then there is no way to send any information to your ad and don't waste your time.

But if they fit your requirements then instead of using normal exit handler, use the following code:

```
function ExitHandler() {


    Enabler.exitQueryString("my zip exit", "click="+ clickVar);
 }

 exitBtn.addEventListener('click', ExitHandler, false);
```