# How to execute function on 'select` element with javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, plugins

I am trying to set the default value of a dropdown box which looks like this:

```
         <select id="schedule_timeslot" name="timeslot">
            <option name="8-10" class="schedule_time" value="0" id="ts0">8am - 10am</option>
            <option name="10-12" class="schedule_time" value="1" id="ts1">10am-12pm</option>
            <option name="12-2" class="schedule_time" value="2" id="ts2" >12pm - 2pm</option>
            <option name="2-4" class="schedule_time" value="3" id="ts3">2pm - 4pm</option>
            <option name="4-6" class="schedule_time" value="4" id="ts4" >4pm - 6pm</option> 
        </select>
```

Based on a URL that looks like this:

```
http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-admin/admin.php?page=Add_Customer&type=add&id=21&date=11/15/2013&timeslot=d3_0
```

The dropdown has timeslots which a user can select to when booking an appointment. The URL has the timeslot value (`timeslot=d3_0`). To do this I was going to add `selected="selected"` attribute to the respective `<option>`. The problem I'm having is that I can't figure out how to execute the algorithm on the selection using jQuery or JavaScript.

I tried using some of the jQuery function like `.load()` and `.on`, but all these need an event (click, mouseover, etc).

So my question is, how do I execute a function on the element I need to? I should also add that I am doing this in a plugin that I'm creating for Wordpress.

Comment: I'm unclear as to how `timeslot=d3_0` corresponds with the respection `<option>` as the names and ids are not the same.

Comment: Right, well if you split the value (d3_0) on the `_`, you have 0, which does correspond. This is the problem that I'm having, in that I need to perform some other logic, before I select a specific element and make an adjustment.

Comment: OK so it sounds like you want Javascript to access the query string and read it's value. A search resulted in this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/647259/javascript-query-string

Comment: I know how to access the string, but thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I quite =understand but check out the following jQuery and let me know if it helps

```
//This listens for when a different option is selected
$('select#schedule_timeslot').change(function() {
    var selectedOptionValue = $(this).val();  //0,1,2 .. etc
    var selectedId = $(this).attr("id");
});
```

To programmably select a desired option

```
$('select#schedule_timeslot').val(desiredValueStr);
```

Comment: Thank you, but I need this to happen on it's own, and not when something is selected.

Comment: Happen on it's own when? On page load?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i understand correctly your question but:

For example, to select a default value of zero makes this

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("schedule_timeslot").val("0")
});
```

**Edit 1:**

Maybe someyhing like this;

```
  $( document ).ready(function() {

  var qs = GetQSParameterByName("timeslot");

     if(qs !=null){
     $("schedule_timeslot").val(qs ) // your value

     }
});

    // read query string from url
     function GetQSParameterByName(name) {

        var match = RegExp('[?&]' + name.toLowerCase() + '=([^&]*)')
              .exec(window.location.search.toLowerCase() );

        return match && decodeURIComponent(match[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
    }
```