# How to get query string parameters from a url

Tags: javascript

How to to get query string parameters from a url

Sample Input -

```
www.boom.com/?frontend=true&challenge=false
```

Sample Output -

```
frontend = true
challenge = false
```

Comment: Well, write the code then.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/647259/javascript-query-string

Answer (score -1):

You could use

```
String frontEnd=request.getParameter("frontend");
String challenge=request.getParameter("challenge");
```

to get the values and then use/show them

Comment: What language is this? Certainly not js.

Comment: @Zirak - As the original question did not tag js this is why the answer is not related.  I don't think it deserves a downvote. It is a poor question.

Comment: @Saurabh Singhal - +1 from me to put you back to 0.

Comment: The original question *was* tagged js: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/22878728/revisions

Comment: @Zirak - Fair enough, then we must have both missed it.  It is still a poor question.

Comment: Very. That doesn't mean it should have irrelevant answers to match.