# How to determine a query string's current value on button click?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have a button that calls a function in the code behind which simply updates the text inside a label. I have a URL that looks like this:

```
http://my-url.com?lang=en
```

If I change the query string, to say `lang=fr` then do not submit the URL (i.e. press enter) but instead press the button, how do I get this new value? `Request.QueryString["lang"];` will return the value of the lasted submitted URL i.e. will return `lang=en` and not `lang=fr`

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code examples, I understand that you don't any `postback` you just change it in JS so it is clear you couldn't get new value in code-behind

To get new query string in server-side you should submit Url or if you wanna work with query string in JS then take a look at this links:

[Get and Set query String in JS](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2009/Sep/07/Get-and-Set-Querystring-Values-in-JavaScript)

[JavaScript query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647259/javascript-query-string)

[Retrieving Query String Values in ASP.NET and Javascript](http://triaslama.wordpress.com/2008/04/12/retrieving-query-string-values-in-aspnet-and-javascript/)

Hope thi will help you.